# C# error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#

I am trying the following code:

```
NMEAData = "$GPGGA,123519,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,1,08,0.9,545.4,M,46.9,M,,*47";

byte[] bData = new byte[256];

bData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(NMEAData);
***NMEAProtocol.ParseBuffer(bData);***

public void ParseBuffer( byte[] buffer)
{
    foreach (byte b in Globals.GBuffer)
    {
        ProcessNMEA(b);
    }
    return;
 }
```

When trying to compile I am getting

> CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Comment: Please provide code that is realitevly correct but demonstrates the problem. Code in current state only allow guesses.

Comment: If I convert this method to static, all the code under need to be converted to be static. How to I create just an object of that class and how do I invoke it as an object instance?

Comment: Side note: please avoid "thank you" and "searched alot" text in the post. To demonstrate search effort make sure to provide article/answers you've found and how it did not work in your case (I've removed all text not related to the problem from your post).

Answer (score 0):

`NMEAProtocol` is not a static class. You need to instantiate it:

```
NMEAProtocol protocol = new NMEAProtocol(); // not sure about constructor. see documentation
protocol.ParseBuffer(bData);
```

In this case, reading articles online it not enough to fix the problem.
It is a basic, fundamental language knowledge.

Comment: Yeldar, this resolved the issue.

Comment: @Sharon Nice to hear it. You can accept this answer if it helped :)